# Is bentonite a hair clarifier?

Tags: natural-remedies, hair

Pretty much every natural hair blogger out there (eg. Naptural85, CurlyNikki) has talked about how [Bentonite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentonite) clays get rid of lint and product buildup. However, I also see other bloggers using the same clays as a hair conditioner. There's a lot of bad science and conflicting beliefs in the community, so I'm wondering if anyone can help me get my facts straight. Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users). Please include some links to the articles in which the claims and counter-claims are made, preferably with a quote from them to prevent link-rot. Also, are the two/three claims contradictory? Could bentonite be a clarifier AND remove lint/product build-up AND act as a conditioner?